# Ruby Gem dependency LoadError on rubygems.org

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm creating a Ruby Gem which has httparty as a dependency.

memair.gemspec

```
lib = File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)

Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name        = 'memair'
  s.version     = '0.0.20'
  s.date        = '2018-09-24'
  s.summary     = 'An SDK for Memair'
  s.description = 'An SDK for Memair allowing easy querying of the GraphQL API'
  s.authors     = ['Greg Clarke']
  s.email       = 'greg@memair.com'
  s.files       = ['lib/memair.rb']
  s.homepage    = 'https://github.com/memair/memair-ruby-sdk'
  s.license     = 'MIT'
  s.add_dependency 'httparty', '~> 0.16'
  s.require_paths = ["lib"]
end
```

lib/memair.rb

```
require 'httparty'

class Memair
  def initialize(access_token)
    #do stuff
  end
end
```

When I install the gem locally or through rubygems.org it installs the dependency and works as expected.

```
$ gem uninstall memair
Successfully uninstalled memair-0.0.22
$ gem uninstall httparty
Remove executables:
    httparty

in addition to the gem? [Yn]  y
Removing httparty
Successfully uninstalled httparty-0.16.2
$ gem install memair
Fetching: httparty-0.16.2.gem (100%)
When you HTTParty, you must party hard!
Successfully installed httparty-0.16.2
Successfully installed memair-0.0.22
2 gems installed
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'memair'
=> true
```

However when I push the gem in my rails project's Gemfile, it fails with...

`'require': cannot load such file -- httparty (LoadError)`

Full Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    53: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    52: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    51: from /Users/greg/Code/memair/memfit/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    50: from /Users/greg/Code/memair/memfit/bin/spring:15:in `require'
    49: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    48: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    47: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    46: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    45: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    44: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    43: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    42: from /Users/greg/Code/memair/memfit/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    41: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
    40: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
    39: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
    38: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    37: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    36: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    35: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    34: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    33: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    32: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    31: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
    30: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    29: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    28: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    27: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
    26: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
    25: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:145:in `block in perform'
    24: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
    23: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
    22: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
    21: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    20: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    19: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    18: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    17: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    16: from /Users/greg/Code/memair/memfit/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
    15: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
    14: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
    13: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
    12: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
    11: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
    10: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
     9: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
     8: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     7: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
     6: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     5: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
     4: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/memair-0.0.20/lib/memair.rb:1:in `<main>'
     3: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
     2: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
     1: from /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
/Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require': cannot load such file -- httparty (LoadError)
```

I've also tried including httparty in my rails project's Gemfile which I assume is an anti pattern and didn't resolve the issue anyway. I've also tried uninstalling both my gem and httparty and rebuilding and uploading to rubygems.org with the same result.

Comment: Super weird, there are no issues when I used ruby 2.5.0. The issues occur with ruby version 2.5.1.

Comment: I have also tried the gem with ruby 2.6.0-preview2 with no issues. I have uninstalled and reinstalled ruby 2.5.1 and the problem remains. Maybe a bug in 2.5.1? I'm using rbenv on macOS. I'll try to replicate the issue with other gems